# Financial Year in SSRS from date

Tags: date, reporting-services, financial, fiscal

I'm trying to get SSRS to show the financial year an issue date was placed

As an example

A date showing 01/04/2018. The financial year column would return 2018
A date showing 31/03/2018. The financial year column would return 2017

```
SELECT

IIF(Month(rTranslog.IssueDate)<=3, Year(rTranslog.IssueDate)-1, 
Year(rTranslog.IssueDate)) AS [FY}

,rTranslog.IssueDate
,rTranslog.Site
,rTranslog.NSVCode
,rProduct.LabelDescription
,rTranslog.Ward
,SUM(rTranslog.Qty) AS Quantity
,SUM(rTranslog.Cost)/100 AS CostGBP

FROM

rTranslog
INNER JOIN rProduct
ON rTranslog.NSVCode = rProduct.NSVCode

GROUP BY
rTranslog.IssueDate
,rTranslog.Site
,rTranslog.NSVCode
,rProduct.LabelDescription
,rTranslog.Ward
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an expression in SSRS like the one below to calculate the financial year

```
= Iif( Month(Fields!calendardate.Value)<=3, Year(Fields!calendardate.Value)-1, Year(Fields!calendardate.Value))
```

For SQL:

```
CASE WHEN Month(rTranslog.IssueDate)<=3 THEN YEAR(rTranslog.IssueDate)-1 ELSE YEAR(rTranslog.IssueDate) END
```

Comment: I have updated my answer with the expression for SQL code

Comment: Perfect ... life saver!